# Small data anomaly detection algo

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, statistics, data-visualization, anomaly-detection

I have the following 3 cases of a numeric metric on a time series(t,t1,t2 etc denotes different hourly comparisons across periods)

If you notice the 3 graphs t(period of interest) clearly has a drop off for image 1 but not so much for image 2 and image 3. Assume this is some sort of numeric metric(raw metric or derived) and I want to create a system/algo which specifically catches case 1 but not case 2 or 3 with t being the point of interest. While visually this makes sense and is very intuitive I am trying to design a way to this in python using the dataframes shown in the picture.

Generally the problem is how do I detect when the time series is behaving very differently from any of the prior weeks.

Edit: When I say different what I really mean is, my metric trends together across periods in t1 to t4 but if they dont and try to separate out of the envelope, that to me is an anomaly. If you notice chart 1 you can see t tries to split out from rest of the tn this is an anomaly for me. in other cases t is within the bounds of other time periods. Hope this helps.

[image: Time series data]

Comment: You need a definition of "different". I can't tell what you want the three graphs to result in from the code?

Answer (score 0):

With small data the best is if you can come up with a good transformation into a simpler representation.

In this case I would try the following:

- Distance to the median along the time-axis. Then a summary of that, could be median, Mean-Squared-Error etc
- Median of the cross-correlation of the signals